# Images appear green in photos app after update to Catalina

Tags: photos, photos.app, catalina

I opened the photos.app in Catalina today and noticed that most thumbnails appear as green pictures. 
Upon double-clicking it show the image correctly, so I'm thinking maybe something is wrong with the caching, but deleting both the `com.apple.Photos.plist` as well as `com.apple.Preview.plist` in `~/Library/Preferences` didn't do anything.

Any suggestions?

Update: I noticed that a lot of my portrait photos are a bit messed up as well (they are all blurred out), but clicking on edit fixes the photo, but not the thumbnail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the last update fixed the issue...